# Getting correct number for the date time entry

Tags: javascript

I need to find out the time in milliseconds (epoch number) for my date string, however it doesn't take into consideration the timezone offset.

```
var dateTimeString = "2022-08-12T06:06:52.237+10:00";
var controlDateTimeString = "2022-08-12T06:06:52.237";

var epochNumber = new Date(dateTimeString).getTime();
var controlEpochNumber = new Date(controlDateTimeString).getTime();

console.log(epochNumber,controlEpochNumber,epochNumber === controlEpochNumber );

//OUTPUT
1660248412237 1660248412237 true
```

So when my code reads it it is always off by 10 hours as it doesn't seem to take it into account.

What do i need to do to take into account the timezone.

EDIT 1 - Showing Testing from Dev Console
[image]

Comment: Could you please indicate in which JavaScript environment the above code was run? I ask as for me in Firefox 103.0.2 and Chrome 104.0.5112.79 on macOS on Apple Silicon (M1) your code seems to work as expected: the output is two `Date` objects with different values and `false`. Casting each `Date` to `Number` via `console.log(Number(epochNumber), Number(controlEpochNumber), epochNumber === controlEpochNumber);` results in output `1660248412237 1660298812237 false` on my computer - the `+10:00` suffix seems to have an effect on the `Date` constructor for me.

Comment: Sorry i realised i missed key code when copying over. Please note the getTime() addition.
Tested on EDGE and Chrome.

Comment: No worries - thanks for the update, @Aeseir. For me the amended code take the specified `+10:00` time zone into consideration in Chrome 104.0.5112.79, Firefox 103.0.2 and Safari 15.4 on macOS on Apple Silicon, outputting `1660248412237 1660298812237 false` in all three browsers. I am testing by pasting the above code into the Developer Tools Console in a new tab and pressing Enter. How are you testing?

Comment: Same way, updated the question with the image to show

Comment: Thanks, @Aeseir. I think I understand the issue now. I am in UTC-4, thus I get two Unix timestamps separated by 50,400,000 ms when I run your code. That is 14 hours - the difference between UTC-4 and UTC+10 (+10:00). I suspect that you are running in UTC+10 and thus getting no difference at all due to `controlDateTimeString` being interpreted as a time in your computer's current time zone. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date for details.) Are you expecting `controlDateTimeString` to be in the UTC (GMT) time zone?

Comment: @MarkA.Fitzgerald yes. I might need to explore this further, it is bugging me lol

Answer (score 0):

This is because, UNIX timestamps are the absolute time since January 1st, 1970 at UTC -- which is constant (by design) no matter the timezone.

It would therefore not make any sense to manipulate the number such that is was 10 hours ahead, since that would no longer be a unix timestamp. You probably want to do whatever you need without actually using a unix epoch as an intermediary.

It really depends what your use case is to know what to do next. Let me know in comments.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, hence i believe i am going about this the wrong way or maybe the wrong function I'm using.

Some of the third party services I'm experimenting with take a epoch number, then display it as time which results in incorrect date as timeoffset is not taken into account. I'm researching the 3rd party tool as well in a parallel to see if i missed anything

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question Comments I believe your intent is that `controlDateTimeString` should be in the UTC (GMT) time zone.  In the `new Date(dateString)` constructor used on line 5 you do not specify a time zone.  [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) does not require a [time zone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Local_time_(unqualified)) to be used in combined date and time representations.  However, the [ECMAScript Standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) does require a time zone to be specified.  [MDN notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) that not conforming to "ISO 8601 format (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`)" my result in "parsing behavior ... implementation-defined and may not work across all browsers".  It appears that not specifying a time zone results in all browsers we've tested interpreting the `dateString` as if it is in the local time zone of the executing computer.

Given the above, chances are appending a `Z` to the `controlDateTimeString` String literal will get the code to behave as you would like it do regardless of the current time zone of the computer on which the code is executed.

```
var dateTimeString = "2022-08-12T06:06:52.237+10:00";
var controlDateTimeString = "2022-08-12T06:06:52.237Z";

var epochNumber = new Date(dateTimeString).getTime();
var controlEpochNumber = new Date(controlDateTimeString).getTime();

console.log(epochNumber,controlEpochNumber,epochNumber === controlEpochNumber );
```

results in the output:

```
//OUTPUT
1660248412237 1660284412237 false
```

on my computer (GMT-4) for a difference of 36000000 ms = 10 hours, which is both the difference between UTC and UTC+10 and, I believe, what you want the code to do.

This code time zone specified in `controlDateTimeString` (as `Z`) should run the same on any computer in any time zone.